# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable Django Filter Values_List

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I've been trying to figure out an error that I can't get past this afternoon.  I am using a Class Based View(DetailView).

Here is my code...

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    book =  list(Author.objects.filter(author_id).values_list('publisher'))
```

When I try to execute my code...

I get....

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I know at times the values_list('publisher') for an Author may sometimes be blank.  How can I get this filter mechanism to bypass the book if the publisher is in fact empty?

I tried to do something like...

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    book =  list(Author.objects.filter(author_id).values_list(None, 'publisher'))
```

But it didn't seem to help.  I also played with the idea of making this reference conditional but that seems unnecessary.  Is there some way to get this code bypassed if in fact the lookup is NONE?

I'm using PostgreSQL.

Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: That filter looks wrong. It should be something like `filter(author_id=author_id)`

Comment: @Wolph Thank you.  Can't believe it was that simple.